# Android: LocationManager in another class

Tags: java, android, class, gps

Thx to your help I managed to make the app work so far! Now I want to separate some code from the other but I Keep getting some Errors...

Error:

```
09-23 17:06:20.129    9324-9324/com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01, PID: 9324
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01/com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
            at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5253)
            at com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01.GPS.<init>(GPS.java:20)
            at com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

class MainActivity

```
package com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//    //GPS
//    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new GPS();

//        //GPS
//        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
//        //CATCHED
//        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
//                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            // TODO: Consider calling
//            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
//            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
//            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
//            //                                          int[] grantResults)
//            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
//            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
//            return;
//        }
//        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


//    //GPS
//    @Override
//    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
//        String str = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
//        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//    }
//
//    //GPS
//    @Override
//    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
//
//
//    }
//
//    //GPS
//    @Override
//    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
//
//    }
//
//    //GPS
//    @Override
//    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
//
//    }

}
```

class GPS

```
package com.example.stefano.aiutomamma01;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPS extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPS() {
        //GPS
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //CATCHED
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    }


    //GPS
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String str = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    //GPS
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    //GPS
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    //GPS
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

}
```

Actually I just separeted some code, but I Keep getting the error. I tryed some way out but it still not working... Something really small im forgetting. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just separating concerns, you should pass your main `Activity` as a constructor parameter to your new class.

Try this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new GPS(this);
}
```

Now use your **MainActivity** context, inside the GPS class.

---

**ADDED**

Although your GPS extend from AppCompatActivity, it is not an Activity.
The Activity needs to be managed by Android.

In my opinion you could use the `MainActivity` context, and let the GPS class as a simple POJO. 
Inside your GPS class, you should add a constructor that receives an Activity.

```
private Activity mainActivity;

public GPS(Activity activity){
   this.mainActivity =  activity;
   locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}
```

Doing things this way, the `MainClass` would extend the `LocationService`. And you just delegate the calls to GPS class methods.

Comment: Hi, I don't get... Can you explain it a bit more? I made new GPS(this), but it didnt work too....

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine! 

The reason I need to give the constructor an "Activity" is because the LocationManager needs one. Right? Im trying to understand it...

Comment: Yes. And just by doing "new GPS()" does not make GPS class an Activity. That's the problem. But you already have an Activity (MainActivity class). So use this activity to provide the locationService, and pass it to you GPS class.

Comment: I guess i did it now. Sry im new.